# Make entry in cell based on current date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to mark an "X" in the F column if the date in B14 (and down) are dates less than the current day and leave any where the dates are greater than the current date blank.

It is just marking an X all the way to the bottom regardless of the date.

```
Sub button_1()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim lrow As Long

On Error Resume Next

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
rCell = Range("B14:B" & lrow)

With Sheet1
    For Each rCell In .Range("F14:F" & lrow).Cells
        If rCell.Value <= Date Then
            rCell.Value = "x"
        ElseIf rCell.Value > Date Then
            rCell.Value = rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this in the Sheet1 private code sheet or in a public module code sheet?

Comment: remove that `On Error Resume Next` and check what are you getting `lrow`. You are comparing column B and looping Column F, bit lRow is coming from Col A. What if Col A is blank.

Comment: @cyboashu, you forgot the incorrect use of xldown from rows.count.

Comment: @Cyboashu the error I'm getting is "Object variable or with block variable not set" not sure what it doesn't like. I did change lrow to column 2, but still same error.

Comment: Changed to up from down. Issue now with rCell = Range("B14:B" & lrow).... same error as above

Comment: because  `rCell = Range("B14:B" & lrow)` is wrong. use `Set rCell = Range("B14:B" & lrow)`

Comment: ahh okay that's a good push. Now it's working but it's not taking the date into account. It's just filing in the value "x" for all the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm going to assume this is in the Sheet1 private code sheet and not in a public module code sheet. In a worksheeet's private code sheet, all Range and Cells default to that worksheet as the parent so there is no need to quaily a parent worksheet unless you are referring to another worksheet.

Run through column B and change column F to suit.

```
Sub button_1()

    Dim i as long, lrow As Long

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlup).Row  '<~~ note xlUp not xlDown

    For i=14 to lrow
        'might as well make sure we aren't looking at blank cells as well
        If cells(i, "B").Value2 <= Date and not isempty(cells(i, "B")) Then
            cells(i, "F") = "x"
        Else     '<~~ no need for further comparisons
            cells(i, "F") = vbnullstring
        End If
    Next i   

End Sub
```